# In Magento 2 How to Override phtml or layout core files?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I had developed "Hello world" extension in Magento 2.

I want to override contact Us form of core files. What is correct way for overriding Contact us form file in Magento 2.

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you got already?

Comment: i have got blank page when i called core contact us form.phtml using contact us phtml reference name.

Comment: In magento 1.x using reference name, we can override core phtml file, right? but in magento 2 structure is different.

Comment: i can not understand  how can i override core file in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved this problem. if you want to override any core files, you simply use reference name and this reference name passed to referenceBlock name="passit".

For conatct us file override, first you get the original file of contactus form.phtml and after that find it's layout file contact_index_index.xml and get the reference name like **"contactForm"**.

**System/core contact_index_index.xml File.**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

This **"contactForm"** reference name passed to our extension layout file in referenceBlock tag. Please show following code.

**Our Extension layout contact_index_index.xml file**

```
<referenceBlock name="contactForm">
    <action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template"xsi:type="string">Test_Overide::form.phtml</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

After this , system contactus form.phtml not called, Our extension form.phtml file called. You can check using Developer front end debugging tool.

Answer (score 12):

Unlike the two previous answers, I chose to **remove the original block** from the layout and **add a new one using my own template**.

We will create a new module, `VendorName_ModuleName`, for which we need to create the following files :

1. `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml`
2. `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml`
3. `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml`
4. `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/composer.json`
5. `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/registration.php`

> Every module in Magento 2 has unique name that’s made up of two parts. The first part is a word that describes the company, individual, or group that built the extension. This is sometimes called the “**vendor**” namespace. The second part of a **module**’s name is a word that describes what the module does.
>
> [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/), in his tutorial *[Magento 2 Hello World Module](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc)*

---

### contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>


        <!-- Remove the original Contact Form -->
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm" remove="true"/>


        <!-- Add a custom Contact Form -->
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="customContactForm" template="My_Module::form.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    

    </body>
</page>
```

In the above code, I removed the original form Block and replaced it by adding my own form inside the `referenceContainer` content.

> **Note :**
>
> In `contact_index_index.xml`, the code `template="My_Module::form.phtml"` refers to your custom contact form's `phtml`.

---

### form.phtml

Now, you need to make the custom form template. You can copy the original one and make modifications to this file.

```
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Us') ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="field note no-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.') ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

### registration.php

Simply replace the `VendorName_ModuleName` with your own.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

---

### module.xml

Replace `VendorName_ModuleName` with your own and `0.0.1` as setup version with the version of your custom module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

---

### composer.json

Of course, if you want to make your new module work, don't forget to add  `composer.json`.

```
 {
"name": "VendorName/ModuleName",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "VendorName\\ModuleName\\": "" },
    "files": [ "registration.php" ]
} }
```

---

### Further Reference

1. Magento 2 documentation for [composer.json](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html)
2. Invoke registration.php in [composer.json](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/component-registration.html#register-autoload) with autoload
3. Explore the code of [Sample Modules](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples) by [Magento on Github](https://github.com/magento).

Comment: what is the difference in advantage/disadvantage of this answer, then just copy the form.phtml to "app/design/frontend/vendor/your_theme/Magento_Contact" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using a plugin.

First you have to override the block and call the `beforeToHtml` method like this:

```
public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description $originalBlock)
{
    $originalBlock->setTemplate('Vendorname_Modulename::description.phtml');
}
```

Comment: Surely a [theme based inheritance](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html) solution would be preferable, rather than adding a plugin to recreate the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Hi easiest way to override core template file:-

```
module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

go to your theme `app/design/frontend/vendor/your_theme/`
follow below steps:

1. Create Magento_Contact folder (Renamed module-contact to Magento-Contact)
2. Create templates folder
3. Create `form.phtm` or copy your `form.phtml` from core and then edit it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create an extension (custom module).

Create a `block`, `etc` and `view` folder from app/magento.

In the `etc` folder create `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Xyz_Contact" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

In the `view` folder create a `layout` folder and place code below in a file named `contact_index_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Xyz\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Xyz_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `templates` folder and place the code below into `form.phtml`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Write Us') ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="field note no-label"><?php echo __('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.') ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?php echo __('Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?php echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In `Block` folder, create a file named `ContactForm.php` and use the code below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Xyz\Contact\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 */
class ContactForm extends Template
{
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }
}
```

Please do not forget to register your module in `app/etc/config.php`, or using the Magento binary tool from the command line: `php -f bin/magento module:enable Xyz_Contact`.

Here `Xyz` is the name of company (the *vendor*) and `Contact` is the module name.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. but this code is not working for me.

Comment: My module in contact_index_index.xml file is not called.. by default magento  original contact_index_index.xml file called

Comment: when i sent request http://localhost/magento2/contact/  in browser , it goes  into my controller . In my controller  $this->_view->renderLayout(); function called .. so it directly called Megento contact us layout file instead of my layout file.

Comment: Hi @Niks - just a note to say that this answer may have been based on a pre-GA release of Magento 2 and might need to be updated. Now, layouts and templates should reside in `view/frontend/layout` or `templates` - this answer is missing the `frontend` part of that path.